# How do I find the minimum price p of various items given these constraints?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have six food items $n_1,n_2,...,n_6$. I would like to purchase a combination of these such that the price is minimized, while there are constraints on the total carbs, protein, and fat contents:

$C_{total} = 2100 ≤ 33n_1+16n_2+29n_3+23n_4+7n_5+89n_6$

$P_{total} = 2100 ≤ 4n_1+7n_2+17n_3+1n_4+27n_5+47n_6$

$F_{total} = 470 ≤ 3n_1+0n_2+12n_3+0n_4+32n_5+3n_6$

$p_{total} = 8.95n_1+2.50n_2+2.65n_3+4.30n_4+6.82n_5+7.08n_6$

Variables must be integers; carbs/fat/protein measured in grams, price in USD.

How would I go about finding the minimum price?

I have thought about using matrices, Lagrange multipliers, vector calculus, but I am overall confused as to what the proper method would be and would like a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: If you had enough of these equations and could stack all the same variables in columns, you could set a 6X6 matrix of coefficients equal to a 1X6 matrix of constants and use Cramer's rule to solve for all the variables. I could be wrong but it might work for inequalities as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Answer (score 0):

Lagrange constrained works. I get n3=30.78, n6=33.55. The rest are zero. Fat and protein boundaries are tight. Price of 319.08

I'm curious what the foods actually are...